# CakePHP - Controller::redirect and Auth->logoutRedirect not working

Tags: php, cakephp, redirect

My CakePHP 2.5.3 app lives in a subdomain (domain/project_name) and apache rewrite rules are working correctly.

After I set App.fullBaseUrl='domain/project_name' in app/Config/core.php, Router::fullBaseUrl() works fine but, all the $this->Controller->redirect and all AuthComponent redirect to http://domain/project_name/project_name/controller/action.

Has anyone else encountered this and how did you fix it?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This is pattern for redirecting after log out:**

```
// app/Controller/AppController.php
class AppController extends Controller {
    //...

    public $components = array(
        'Session',
        'Auth' => array(
            'loginRedirect' => array(
                'controller' => 'posts',
                'action' => 'index'
            ),
            'logoutRedirect' => array(      // <-- Let's focus at here.
                'controller' => 'pages',
                'action' => 'display',
                'home'
            ),
            'authenticate' => array(
                'Form' => array(
                    'passwordHasher' => 'Blowfish'
                )
            )
        )
    );

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('index', 'view');
    }
    //...
}
```

Source: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authentication-login-and-logout

In your problem context, check `logoutRedirect` configuration array.

**If you want handle redirecting by other ways:**

```
public function logout() {
    return $this->redirect($this->Auth->logout());
}
```

Source: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html#authentication-login-and-logout